Compatibility of complex and p-adic Hodge decompositions
My question concerns the compatibility of the complex and p-adic Hodge decompositions.
To make this more precise, fix an isomorphism $\sigma: \mathbb{C}_{p}  \simeq  \mathbb{C}$, and let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ in $\mathbb{C}_{p}$, and $\overline{K}$ its algebraic closure in $\mathbb{C}_{p}$. Let $X$ be a projective variety over $K$, e.g. an abelian variety. Denote by $X^\text{an}_{\sigma, \mathbb{C}}$ the complex analytification of $X_\mathbb{C}$, the complex variety obtained by base-change from $K$ to $\mathbb{C}$ via $\sigma$.
In this case one may combine some well known comparison isomorphisms to build the following diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
\gamma \in H^1_\text{sing}(X^\text{an}_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \mathbb Q) \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb C @>\sim>\text{(complex) Hodge}> H^0(X^\text{an}_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \Omega^1) \oplus H^1(X^\text{an}_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \mathcal O) \\
@V\sim V\mathrm{id} \otimes \sigma^{-1}V @V\sim V\text{GAGA}V \\
H^1_\text{sing}(X^\text{an}_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \mathbb Q) \otimes_{\mathbb Q} \mathbb Q_p \otimes_{\mathbb Q_p, \sigma} \mathbb C @. H^0(X_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \Omega^1) \oplus H^1(X_{\sigma, \mathbb C}, \mathcal O) \\
@V\sim V\text{singular to étale}V @V\sim V\sigma^{-1}V \\
H^1_\text{ét}(\sigma(X_{\overline K}), \mathbb Q_p) \otimes_{\mathbb Q_p, \sigma} \mathbb C @. H^0(X_{\mathbb C_p}, \Omega^1) \oplus H^1(X_{\mathbb C_p}, \mathcal O) \\
@V\sim V\sigma^{-1} \otimes \sigma^{-1}V @V\sim V\mathrm{can} \oplus \mathrm{can}(-1)V \\
H^1_\text{ét}(X_{\overline K}, \mathbb Q_p) \otimes \mathbb C_p @>\sim>\text{(p-adic) Hodge–Tate}> H^0(X_K, \Omega^1) \otimes_K \mathbb C_p \oplus H^1(X_K, \mathcal O) \otimes_K \mathbb C_p(-1).
\end{CD}$$
In this diagram one may ask whether an element $\gamma$ in the top left ($H^{1}_\text{sing}$) would land in the same direct summand in the bottom right (e.g. say $H^0(X_{K}, \Omega^1) \otimes _{K} \mathbb{C}_p$) regardless of whether one goes down the left or the right hand side in the diagram? Or would $\gamma$ even go to identical elements, i.e. would the diagram be commutative?
I found some related literature, e.g. Kisin–Wortmann, A note on Artin motives 2003 or Deligne–Illusie Relèvements modulo $p^2$ et décomposition du complexe de de Rham 1987. To my understanding, the former discusses a related but still different question. And the latter would be more concerned with the dimensions of the decompositions.

$\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbb{Q}}\newcommand{\et}{\acute{e}t}\newcommand{\oK}{\overline{K}}\newcommand{\obQ}{\overline{\bQ}}\newcommand{\bG}{\mathbb{G}}\newcommand{\bZ}{\mathbb{Z}}\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbb{N}}$These decompositions are in general different. We can see this by looking at how they change when the isomorphism $\sigma$ is changed. Note also that the diagram you drew depends on the choice of a compatible system of $p$-th power roots of unity in $\bC_p$, to identify $\bC_p(-1)$ with $\bC_p$ in the Hodge-Tate decomposition. Once $i=\sqrt{-1}\in \bC$ is chosen, the field $\bC$ comes with a "canonical" choice of roots of unity given by $\exp(2\pi i/n)$, so we could transport these along $\sigma$ and use for the identification. But your first question does not need this choice, and it has a negative answer as well.
We have a $\bQ_p$-vector space $H^1_{\et}(X_{\oK},\bQ_p)$ whose scalar extension to $\bC_p$ is equipped with the Hodge-Tate decomposition: it is decomposed into a direct sum of two subspaces, and that decomposition does not depend on any choices. If we choose an embedding $\sigma_0:\oK\hookrightarrow \bC$ then $H^1_{\et}(X_{\oK},\bQ_p)$ is identified with $H^1_{\mathrm{sing}}(X(\bC),\bQ_p)$ where $X(\bC)$ is the topological space of $\bC$-points of the base change of $X_{\oK}$ along $\sigma_0$. Given any embedding $\sigma_1:\bQ_p\hookrightarrow \bC$ the scalar extension $H^1_{\mathrm{sing}}(X(\bC),\bQ_p)\otimes_{\bQ_p,\sigma_1}\bC$ then has a Hodge decomposition into two $\bC$-subspaces. Finally, if we have an identification $\sigma_2:\bC\simeq\bC_p$ then we can turn this into a decomposition of $H^1_{\et}(X_{\oK},\bQ_p)\otimes_{\bQ_p}\bC_p$ which depends on $\sigma_0,\sigma_1$, and $\sigma_2$.
In the formulation of the question we have $\sigma=\sigma_2^{-1}$ and $\sigma_0,\sigma_1$ are induced from $\sigma$. Suppose that for one choice of $\sigma$ the two decompositions on $H^1_{\et}(X_{\oK},\bQ_p)\otimes_{\bQ_p}\bC_p$ were equal. Let us replace $\sigma$ by $\sigma\circ\tau$ for any automorphism $\tau\in \mathrm{Aut}(\bC_p/\obQ_p)$ of $\bC_p$ that restricts to identity on $\obQ_p$. Then $\sigma_0$ and $\sigma_1$ are unchanged and the decomposition of $H^1_{\et}(X_{\oK},\bQ_p)\otimes_{\bQ_p}\bC_p$ coming from the Hodge decomposition is simply composed with the automorphism $\mathrm{id}\otimes\tau$. If the two decompositions were the same for $\sigma\circ\tau$ as well, it would in particular mean that the Hodge-Tate decomposition remains unchanged when twisted by any $\tau\in \mathrm{Aut}(\bC_p/\obQ_p)$.
We can see explicitly that this is false for any Tate elliptic curve  (in fact this fails for all elliptic curves without formal complex multiplication -- see https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.05242). If the rigid-analytic space associated to $X$ has the form $\bG^{\mathrm{an}}_m/q^{\bZ}$ for some $q\in K$ with $v(q)>0$ then a choice for a basis of the Tate module $$T_pX=\lim X[p^n]=\lim\{a\in \bG_m(\oK)\mid a^{p^n}\in q^{\bZ}\}$$ of $X$ is $e_1=(\zeta_{p^n})_{n\in\bN}, e_2=(q^{1/p^n})_{n\in\bN}$, the elements given by compatible collections of $p$-th power roots of $1$ and $q$. Then the Hodge-Tate decomposition $T_pX\otimes_{\bQ_p}\bC_p$ is given by one-dimensional subspaces $\langle e_1\rangle$ and $\langle ae_1+e_2\rangle$ where $a\in\bC_p$ is an element such that $g(a)=\chi_{\mathrm{cycl}}(g)^{-1}(a-c(g))$ for all $g\in \mathrm{Gal}(\oK/K)$ where $c(g)\in \bZ_p$ is the value on $g$ of the Kummer cocycle corresponding to $q$: it is characterised by $g(q^{1/p^n})=\zeta_{p^n}^{c(g)}q^{1/p^n}$.
The period $a$ cannot lie in $\obQ_p$, because if it did, the value $c(g)\cdot (\chi_{\mathrm{cycl}}(g)-1)^{-1}$ would be constant for $g$ from an open subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(\oK/K)$ which is really not the case.
We could also have argued on the side of complex Hodge theory that if the two decompositions were the same for all $\sigma$, it would contradict the fact that periods of complex Hodge structures are in general trancendental.
